# No me puedo conectar a mi base de datos en Docker desde pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

- Con el comando "docker-machine ip" obtengo la ip y lo ingreso en el campo "Host name/adreess".

[image: pgAdmin]

- Me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Este es el puerto de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que exponer el puerto del contenedor al host.
cuando haces el docker run la opcion -p : es para exponer puertos
ej:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 postgres:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo inconveniente tengo ejecutando la imagen, pero le pongo stop y le ejecuto con el puerto y me da error, o en donde debo cambiar el puerto de una imagen existen de una aplicación.

Comment: Hola Darwin, por favor no uses la sección de respuestas para replicar a una pregunta, usa en cambio la sección de comentarios o formula una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.